# Should I use a database instead of serialized files?

Tags: persistence

I am working in my first real world application that consists of keeping track of medical studies of a medium size medical office. The system needs to keep track of doctors, users, patients, study templates and study reports. The purpose of this program is to apply preformatted study template for any possible study, keep track of each patient's study and keep a easy to find file system. Each study report is saved in an specific folder as an html file that can be used or printed from Windows directly.

I estimate that at any given time would be about 20 active doctors, 30 different study templates, 12 users; the patients and study reports would be cumulative an will remain active indefinitely. I estimate that we are talking about 2000 new patient and 6000 new study reports a year.

I have almost completed the job, but initially I chose to store the data in a serialized file and I did not consider to use a database instead. Now, considering that the size of the data will rapidly grow, I believe that I should consider to work with a database instead.  For many different reasons, especially I am concerned about the serialized file choice because I noticed that any change that I may make in the future in any class may conflict with the serialized file and stops me from reopening it. I appreciate any comments, how large a file is too large to work with? It is a serialize file acceptable in this case please pass me any ideas or comments. Thanks for the help

Comment: You really did not use an ORM framework like Hibernate/JPA?  How did you realize searching for patients? Do you read the whole database into memory? I so hope it is an exercise.

Comment: That's the point. Originaly that was the idea, but i realize that i will be sturating the memory in no time. A brief of the structure it is as this:

Comment: i have an object i called program, program have doctors, users, pacients, study templates and study reports. in the other hand study report hold an intance of a doctor, template, pacient and so on. What i was doig was saving the object program and all the asociates classes in one file. I did not use a database and therefore i realized i was pulling all the info to the memory at all the times.

Comment: i see, Sams answer fits really good.

Answer (score 2):

Your concern about breaking compatibility with these files is absolutely reasonable.
I solved the same problem in a small inventory project by taking these steps:

- Setup of a DB server (MySQL)
- Integration of hibernate into the project
- Reimplementation of the serializable classes within a new package using JPA annotations (if the DB schema won't break, add the annotations to existing classes)
- Generation of the DB schema using the JPA entitites
- Implementation of an importer for existing objects (deserialization, conversion and persisting with referential integrity.
- Import and validation of existing data objects
- Any required refactoring from old classes to the new JPA entities within the whole project
- Removal of old classes and their importer (should slumber in a repository)

Comment: Unfortunately, you last comment it is far beyond my capability to do at this moment. In other words, I can not understand what you are mention above due lock of knoledge. along with others I don't know what hibernate into the project means.

Comment: Hibernate is a JPA (Java Persistence API) implementation, which basically connects java classes to DB table rows (entities). Learning all this stuff will surely take its time, but depending on future projects it's worth it. Peter Lawrey mentioned the XMLEncoder: If you don't need to execute complicated queries, an XML file implementation (I used the castor library once) will also greatly loosen the bindings between java classes and data files regarding code changes.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will look into more details JPA what it seems to be the way to go. I am still ages away (it seems) but hopefully eventually I will get there. For now i think I should research in DB management. I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I wish you great success!

Answer (score 1):

Most people will say that you should use a database regardless.  If this is a professional application you can't risk the data being corrupted and is a real possibility e.g. due to a bug in your code and someone using the program incorrectly.

It is the value of the data, not the size which matters here. Say it has been running for a year and the file becomes unusable. Are you going to tell them they should enter all the data again from scratch?

If its just an exercise, I still suggest you use a database as you will learn something.  A popular choice is to use hibernate and it is CV++. ;)

Comment: it is a real project for a real clinic with real pacients. I agree how important is the value of the data, but I am also concerned in the size, since after a couple years i may have 15 or 18k records. The way I have it setup now the application is loading everyrecord to the memory all the time. Buy saying this I am kind of self answer my original quesiton, but i am stack since i am having a lot of trouble understanding conceptual questions about how a database works. (i have read so much material but i dont seem to get it)

Comment: I load 4 billion records into memory in Java (no database) and it's not a problem because a) I don't change it, it's just source data b) I can recreate it easily.  The size doesn't matter, only it's value and the cost of recreating it.

Comment: ok. i am impress, I wouldn't imagine how much info you can handle in memory. that takes me back to reliability and expandability in the event that i need to add new instance variables to my objects.

Comment: I didn't get them for a long time and I still avoid them where I can. All the same, you will have to learn the basics of how to use a database at some point (MySQL is a good start)

Comment: When I want more data I rebuild my working data set.  This is because it is extracted from a much larger data set which is a reference for me.  The point is Java can handle much more data than most people think.  The issue is the risk of using a plain file esp a binary one is too great. As simple first step I suggest using an XMLEncoder instead of Java Serialization. It should involve minimal changes to your code but it can be backed up and manually fix as needed.